# How to go through a column of arrays and flag each row based on is it contains an item in a list?

Tags: pandas, pyspark, databricks

I have an array with two columns. The first contains a name and the second contains an arraylist of items with each name being different and each arraylist within the rows containing different values that have been aggregated together. I then have a list of items. I want to flag the rows in which the array contains a value that is also in the list with a yes or a no if nothing matches. This is the code I have thus far:

```
 df1 = df.withColumn("ITEM_FLG", 
              f.when(f.array_intersect(f.col("ITEM_DESCR_SET"), item_list), f.lit("Y"))
              .otherwise("N")
             )
```

'ITEM_FLG" is the column I want to create with the values, 'ITEM_DESCR_SET' is the column that contains the array lists, and 'item_list' contains the list of items I am checking for. When I run the code, however, I get '**TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column**' which is because of the item_list I believe.

need this for pyspark ideally or pandas if necessary. thank you!

Comment: Did you try`isin` for example `f.col("ITEM_DESCR_SET").isin(item_list)`. I believe in your case `df.withColumn("ITEM_FLG", f.when(f.col("ITEM_DESCR_SET").isin(item_list), f.lit("Y")).otherwise("N"))` You can combine the boolean output of isin using `np.any`

Comment: yeah I did, no cigar.  .withColumn("ITEM_FLG", 
              f.when(f.array_intersect(f.col("ITEM_DESCR_SET").isin(item_list)), f.lit("Y"))
              .otherwise("N")) ... 'array_intersect() missing 1 required positional argument: 'col2''

Comment: You do not need intersect, did you try just the isin with np.any?

Comment: can you share details on how your array column looks like and what's the `item_list`?

Comment: i've shared a simple example of how to do it. it can be updated to suit your needs. if you share more details around the dataframe columns and the list, i can update the example accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`arrays_overlap()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_overlap.html#pyspark-sql-functions-arrays-overlap) to check if any of the items from the `item_list` is in your array column. But, we'd need to convert the `item_list` list to a pyspark array field.

Here's a simple example.

```
data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['names_array'])

# +------------------+
# |       names_array|
# +------------------+
# |   [foo, bar, baz]|
# |[karen, sam, john]|
# +------------------+

# root
#  |-- names_array: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

name_list = ['bar', 'carter', 'samantha']

# convert the list to a pyspark ArrayType()
name_psarray = func.array(*[func.lit(k) for k in name_list])
# Column<'array(bar, carter, samantha)'>

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('name_flag',
               func.when(func.arrays_overlap('names_array', name_psarray), func.lit('Y')).
               otherwise(func.lit('N'))
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +------------------+---------+
# |names_array       |name_flag|
# +------------------+---------+
# |[foo, bar, baz]   |Y        |
# |[karen, sam, john]|N        |
# +------------------+---------+
```